Vulkan - VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER error in Apple M2
With this code:
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
class HelloTriangleApplication {

public:
    void run() {
        initWindow();
        initVulkan();
        mainLoop();
        cleanup();
    }
private:
    VkInstance instance;
    
    void initWindow() {
    }
    void initVulkan() {
        createVulkanInstance();
    }
    
    void mainLoop() {
    }
    
    void cleanup() {
        vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
    }
    
    void createVulkanInstance() {
        VkApplicationInfo appInfo{};
        appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
        appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
        appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;
        
        VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo{};
        instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
        setRequiredExtensions(&instanceCreateInfo);
                
        VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &instance);
        if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Vulkan instance. Error code: " + std::to_string(static_cast<int>(result)));
        }
        delete [] instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames;
    }
   
    void setRequiredExtensions(VkInstanceCreateInfo* instanceCreateInfo) {
        std::vector<const char*> requiredExtensions;

        #ifdef __APPLE__
        requiredExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME);
        requiredExtensions.push_back("VK_KHR_portability_subset");
        requiredExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME);
        instanceCreateInfo->flags = VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR;
        #endif
       
        
        const char** enabledExtensions = new const char*[requiredExtensions.size()];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < requiredExtensions.size(); i++) {
            enabledExtensions[i] = requiredExtensions[i];
        }
        
        instanceCreateInfo->enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(requiredExtensions.size());
        instanceCreateInfo->ppEnabledExtensionNames = enabledExtensions;
        
        std::cout << "Requesting extensions:" << std::endl;
        for (const auto& ext : requiredExtensions) {
            std::cout << "\t" << ext << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    const char* vk_icd = std::getenv("VK_ICD_FILENAMES");
    const char* vk_layer = std::getenv("VK_LAYER_PATH");
    if (!vk_icd) throw std::runtime_error("VK_ICD_FILENAMES environment variable is not set");
    if (!vk_layer) throw std::runtime_error("VK_LAYER_PATH environment variable is not set");
    #ifndef NDEBUG
    std::cout << "VK_ICD_FILENAMES: " << (vk_icd ? vk_icd : "Not set") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "VK_LAYER_PATH: " << (vk_layer ? vk_layer : "Not set") << std::endl;
    #endif
    
    HelloTriangleApplication app;
    
    try {
        app.run();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

...I am getting VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER on vkCreateInstance.

Beginning with the 1.3.216 Vulkan SDK, the Vulkan Loader is strictly enforcing the new VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_subset extension. The most likely cause of this error message on instance creation is failure to adhere to this extension, which prevents applications on all platforms from selecting by default a non-conformant Vulkan implementation without opting in. MoltenVK is currently not fully conformant, and thus supporting this extension is necessary for building robust and portable Vulkan-based applications that are good citizens in the Vulkan ecosystem.
Opting in is simple. First add the VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR bit to your VkInstanceCreateInfo structure's .flags member, then add two instance extensions to your instance extensions list: VK_KHR_portability_enumeration, and VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2.

Which, I did in:
#ifdef __APPLE__
requiredExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME);
requiredExtensions.push_back("VK_KHR_portability_subset");
requiredExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME);
instanceCreateInfo->flags = VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR;
#endif

doesnt work, still error -9.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72791361/22757599

Enable the VK_KHR_portability_enumeration instance extension
Add (or set) the VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR flag for your instance create info
Enable the VK_KHR_portability_subset device extension

I cannot set a device extension without creating instance. I already set the first two. doesn't work.
but you know what is funny? there is only one solution to this. and every single solution is same.
https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/11a1kq4/problem_with_vulkan_in_apple_m2/
https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/6101
https://vulkan-tutorial.com/FAQ
VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER with Mac OS and Vulkan MoltenVK
I could line up a Berlin wall of links here just with this questions and same answers, but you got my point. nobody, literally not a soul said "hey this didn't work for me, here, take this", IT IS ONLY THIS SOLUTION. enable 2 extensions, set 1 flag, and voila, works for everyone. except me.
help

On my M1 mac with MoltenVK 1.2.10 and Vulkan SDK 1.3.290, the vkCreateInstance call returns -7 because VK_KHR_portability_subset is a device extension, not an instance extension. If I remove that the vkCreateInstance call passes. What is your situation like and how did you configure those VK_ environment variables?

@Botje environment variables are passed from Xcode directly, ICD_FILENAMES = /VulkanSDK/1.3.290.0/macOS/share/vulkan/icd.d/MoltenVK_icd.json, LAYER_PATH = VulkanSDK/1.3.290.0/macOS/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d. Also, no, same error if I delete portability_subset. Still -9

I'm afraid you have no choice but to compile MoltenVK yourself and step into the implementation to figure out why it behaves differently for you.

If it is going to that matter, I would much rather to work on Arch Linux or Windows. :(

Like if there is no easy solution to this, then I am going to close this question

Shrug. You could try bumping MVK_CONFIG_LOG_LEVEL to 4, maybe there's something in the debug output. But I cannot reproduce your problem otherwise.

I get the device extension automatically without asking for it, but you don't really get to that part yet..

Yes behaviorals are very different for my setup, weirdly. Logs doesnt show anything significant, I couldnt even compile MoltenVK. thanks for trying and all the helps mate but I think we are going to dead end @Botje
